# if checkbox is checked press enter to trigger button click

Tags: jquery, forms, button, checkbox, enter

I have a form which shows 1 question at a time and i have to click next in order to go to the next question. The user have to select one option to move to the other questions. I want to do is if the user selects a option from the checkbox and press enter it will trigger the next button and move to the other questions. i cant possibly do it. what is wrong with my code? 
jquery code..

```
$('input[name="trading_for_at_least_6_months"]:checked').keypress(function (event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $(".comnext1").click();
}});
```

I am trying to code is to see if any of the options is checked by checking the input names and if it is, when enter key is pressed trigger next button. I have other next button so i dont want to trigger them too.

Comment: Have you tried something like this on enter key press event `$(".comnext1").trigger('click');`

Comment: Why do you simulate a click on `.comnext1` instead of doing a direct call to the function that is triggered on clicking the button?

Comment: I used same kind of code in case of text input field it worked. Didnt think the of other way. And i was confused as what i did wrong and as why my code doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
    if($('input[name="trading_for_at_least_6_months"]').is(':checked')) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            alert(1);
            $('.comnext1').trigger('click');
            return false;
        }
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

Remove the alert in above code it's for testing that event is working on submit and button is getting clicked.

Comment: What was wrong in my code. If u please tell em what was exactly happening in my code that it didnt work.

Comment: the problem was `keypress` event, that never works on checkbox, possible events used with checkbox are `click` and `change' event, and you were checking `keypress` event to control `enter` button action.